# How to debug Reports > Products > Products Ordered collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, reports, query, debugging

I found that Magento Reports module is very tricky and confusing to debug.

Though I got that the `Reports > Product > Products Ordered` collection is generated from `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php` `soldAction`, I cannot seem to get query or data for debugging purposes when I change it's Grid's (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid) `_prepareCollection` to below.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        $debugCollection = $this->getCollection()->initReport('reports/product_sold_collection');
        $size = $debugCollection->getSize();
        $debug = $debugCollection->debug();
        //or
        $debugQuery = $debugCollection->getSelect();
        //or
        $debugData = $debugCollection->getData();
        $this->getCollection()->initReport('reports/product_sold_collection');
        return $this;
    }
```

All functions `getData()`, `debug()` & `getSelect()` seem to be undefined in that module class hierarchy.

Comment: Is solve your problem?

Comment: Yes my problem is solved with this answer but if you still have any other easier way, then please post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go and find the collection model in question you can always, temporarily while debugging define the `_afterLoad` method on the class and then do your debugging their. For example in this case if you go to the class: `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Sold_Collection` and define the method:

```
public function _afterLoad()
{
    echo $this->getSelect();
    return parent::_afterLoad(); 
}
```

You will when generating a report get the query used. When you are done debugging remember to remove the code.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I was stuck in debugging scenario, you really provided a resourceful headstart. By any chance I could do this same thing in php and add `getData` or `getItems` function to get specific columns in this same function, where do I need to define this `getData` for that ?

Comment: Also what is `_afterLoad`, can you provide some useful links for understanding that ?